# How to reference a Javascript file in a Node.js enviroment

Tags: node.js, firebase-hosting

```
npm install -g firebase-tools
firebase login
firebase init
firebase emulators:start
```

I did all this, and every single source/blog tells me that node.js would work after I did this, but it doesn't, why?
I am unable to perform any node.js functions in any script inside the public folder.

I also seem to be unable to reference, via `<script src=""></script>"` (in the `index.html` inside the `public` folder), any file outside of the `public` folder, so all of my scripts have to be inside the public folder.

Where is this node environment I was told about?

I also tried `firebase serve`

Also, what is the difference between `firebase serve` and `firebase emulators:start`?

I'm doing something really wrong, aren't I?

Comment: `<script src...>` is invalid javascript syntax so node won't be able to parse that. Have you used any other scripting language before like ruby or python?

Comment: I'm making a web app, `<script>` is in an `index.html` in the `public` folder.
Thanks for bringing this to my attention I will edit it.

Comment: Are you actually writing a web app using a bundler like Webpack, Vite, Rollup, etc? If so, follow [these instructions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup). If not, I suspect you'll want to use the [CDN method](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/alt-setup) in your HTML file(s).

Comment: The `serve` command starts a simple web server to serve your static HTML, JS, etc files. You need a web server (as opposed to opening the HTML directly) in order to communicate with the Firebase servers. The `emulators:start` starts local instances of Firebase services like Cloud Firestore, Authentication, etc

Comment: A web server? Like a main.js that has an `http.createServer(function() {}).listen(3000)`? I do have that, but running `node main.js` in the terminal returns a `ReferenceError: window is not defined` at `C:\Users\budiy\OneDrive\Documents\GitHub\TugasPBM\node_modules\@firebase\analytics\dist\index.cjs.js:183`

Comment: Which leads me to believe that `main.js` is to never run. Also I already converted the `import` to `require`